# IsTrue/False in Spring Data query creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

Does Spring Data query creation supports IsTrue/False in the query creation?

I found this section http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation in an older version documentation, but I cannot find something similar for the latest version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, simply use `IsTrue` or `IsFalse` your repository methods:

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  Iterable<Person> findByActiveIsTrue();
}
```

This is also listed in the [keywords section of the reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e2609).